# Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.2.0

Tags: php, composer-php, guzzle

After a `composer require irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk ^2.0` went ok, now I'm trying to include another package with `composer require erlangb/betfair` but this is what i get from composer:

```
Using version ^0.2.0 for erlangb/betfair
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - erlangb/betfair 0.2.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle-services 0.5.* -> satisfi
able by guzzlehttp/guzzle-services[0.5.0].
    - Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.2.0
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle-services 0.5.0 requires guzzlehttp/command 0.7.* -> sati
sfiable by guzzlehttp/command[0.7.0, 0.7.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/command 0.7.1
    - Installation request for erlangb/betfair ^0.2.0 -> satisfiable by erlangb/
betfair[0.2.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.2.0
    - guzzlehttp/command 0.7.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~5.0 -> satisfiable by
 guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.0, 6.2.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.1, 6.2.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.2, 6.2.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.3, 6.2.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.1.0, 6.2.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.2.0, 6.2.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.0, 6.2.0].
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle == 6.2.0.0 -> satisfiable by gu
zzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.0].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

What i could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In short

In composer you can't have two versions of the same package, since it would cause autoload collisions due to the nature of namespaces in PHP.

#### The error

The `telegram-bot-sdk` package requires version `~6.0`, as you can see in it's [`composer.json`](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/blob/master/composer.json)

```
"require": {
  ...
  "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
  ...
},
```

but [`erlangb/betfair` `0.2.0`](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/command#0.7.0) requires `~5.0`, [`guzzlehttp/command` `0.7.0`](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/command#0.7.0) also requires `~5.0` which in turn is required by [`guzzlehttp/guzzle-services` `0.5.0`](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle-services). Unfortunately, the `dev-master` branch of `erlangb/betfair` is still using the old Guzzle version, so this is no good. I suggest you either find an alternative betfair package or fork and update it yourself.